# Error when trying to add a custom position adjustment to a package in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I am trying to create position adjustments for *ggplot2* that explicitly control the way points are spread out along the (x)-axis (rather than just adding a random jitter).  I successfully used the examples `position_jitter` and `position_jitterdodge` to create simple variants that should for my purposes:

```
PositionSpread <- ggproto("PositionSpread", Position,
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),
  
  setup_params = function(self, data) {
    list(
      sep = self$sep %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * .05),
      max_width = self$max_width %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * 0.4)
    )
  },
  
  compute_layer = function(self, data, params, layout) {

    f <- function(sep, i, n) {
      m <- ceiling(max(n) / 2)
      
      ifelse(
        as.logical(n %% 2), 
        sep * c(0, rep(1:m, each = 2) * rep(c(-1, 1), m))[i],
        sep * (rep(1:m, each = 2)[i] - 1 / 2) * rep(c(-1, 1), m)
      )
    }
    
    trans_x <- if(params$max_width > 0) function(df) {
      df |>
        group_by(x, y) |>
        mutate(
          i = 1:n(),
          n = n(),
          sep = pmin(params$sep, 2 * params$max_width / n),
          adj = f(sep, i, n)
        ) |>
        magrittr::extract("adj")
    }
    
    x_aes <- intersect(ggplot2:::ggplot_global$x_aes, names(data))
    y_aes <- intersect(ggplot2:::ggplot_global$y_aes, names(data))
    x <- if (length(x_aes) == 0) 0 else data[[x_aes[1]]]
    y <- if (length(y_aes) == 0) 0 else data[[y_aes[1]]]
    dummy_data <- vctrs::new_data_frame(list(x = x, y = y), nrow(data))
    x_adj <- trans_x(dummy_data)
    
    
    # Apply jitter
    transform_position(data, function(x) x + x_adj)
  }
)

position_spread <- function(max_width = NULL, sep = NULL) {
  ggproto(NULL, PositionSpread,
    max_width = max_width,
    sep = sep
  )
}
```

and

```
position_spreaddodge <- function(spread.width = NULL, spread.sep = NULL,
  dodge.width = 0.75) {

  ggplot2::ggproto(NULL, PositionSpreaddodge,
    spread.width = spread.width,
    spread.sep = spread.sep,
    dodge.width = dodge.width
  )
}

PositionSpreaddodge <- ggproto("PositionSpreaddodge", Position,
  spread.width = NULL,
  spread.sep = NULL,
  dodge.width = NULL,
  
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),
  
  setup_params = function(self, data) {
    flipped_aes <- has_flipped_aes(data)
    data <- flip_data(data, flipped_aes)
    spread.width <- self$spread.width %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * 0.4)
    # Adjust the x transformation based on the number of 'dodge' variables
    dodgecols <- intersect(c("fill", "colour", "linetype", "shape", "size", "alpha"), colnames(data))
    if (length(dodgecols) == 0) {
      abort("`position_jitterdodge()` requires at least one aesthetic to dodge by")
    }
    ndodge    <- lapply(data[dodgecols], levels)  # returns NULL for numeric, i.e. non-dodge layers
    ndodge    <- length(unique(unlist(ndodge)))
    
    list(
      dodge.width = self$dodge.width,
      spread.sep = self$spread.sep %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * .05),
      spread.width = spread.width / (ndodge + 2),
      flipped_aes = flipped_aes
    )
  },
  
  compute_panel = function(data, params, scales) {
    data <- flip_data(data, params$flipped_aes)
    data <- ggplot2:::collide(data, params$dodge.width, "position_jitterdodge", ggplot2:::pos_dodge,
      check.width = FALSE)
    
    f <- function(sep, i, n) {
      m <- ceiling(max(n) / 2)
      
      ifelse(
        as.logical(n %% 2), 
        sep * c(0, rep(1:m, each = 2) * rep(c(-1, 1), m))[i],
        sep * (rep(1:m, each = 2)[i] - 1 / 2) * rep(c(-1, 1), m)
      )
    }
    
    trans_x <- if(params$spread.width > 0) function(df) {
      df |>
        group_by(x, y) |>
        mutate(
          i = 1:n(),
          n = n(),
          sep = pmin(params$spread.sep, 2 * params$spread.width / n),
          adj = f(sep, i, n)
        ) |>
        magrittr::extract2("adj")
    }
    
    x_aes <- intersect(ggplot2:::ggplot_global$x_aes, names(data))
    y_aes <- intersect(ggplot2:::ggplot_global$y_aes, names(data))
    x <- if (length(x_aes) == 0) 0 else data[[x_aes[1]]]
    y <- if (length(y_aes) == 0) 0 else data[[y_aes[1]]]
    dummy_data <- vctrs::new_data_frame(list(x = x, y = y), nrow(data))
    x_adj <- trans_x(dummy_data) |> unclass()

    
    # Apply Spread
    data <- transform_position(data, function(x) x + x_adj)
    flip_data(data, params$flipped_aes)
  }
)
```

These functions both appear to work fine.  Now, I'm trying to add them to an internal package so that I have easy access to them across multiple projects, but I'm running into an issue with documentation.  I've added `Depends: ggplot2 (>= 3.0.0)` in the DESCRIPTION file.

Using `position_spreaddodge` as example, I've added the following comments:

```
#' Simultaneously dodge and spread points
#'
#' This is primarily used for aligning points generated through
#' `geom_point()` with dodged boxplots (e.g., a `geom_boxplot()` with
#' a fill aesthetic supplied).
#'
#' @family position adjustments
#' @param spread.width degree of spread in x direction.  Once points get spread to this amount, the space between points starts being compressed
#' @param spread.sep separation between points before compression.
#' @param dodge.width the amount to dodge in the x direction. Defaults to 0.75,
#'   the default `position_dodge()` width.

#' @export


position_spreaddodge <- function(spread.width = NULL, spread.sep = NULL,
  dodge.width = 0.75) {

  ggplot2::ggproto(NULL, PositionSpreaddodge,
    spread.width = spread.width,
    spread.sep = spread.sep,
    dodge.width = dodge.width
  )
}

#' @format NULL
#' @usage NULL
#' @export
PositionSpreaddodge <- ggproto("PositionSpreaddodge", Position,
  spread.width = NULL,
  spread.sep = NULL,
  dodge.width = NULL,
  
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),
  
  setup_params = function(self, data) {
    flipped_aes <- has_flipped_aes(data)
    data <- flip_data(data, flipped_aes)
    spread.width <- self$spread.width %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * 0.4)
    # Adjust the x transformation based on the number of 'dodge' variables
    dodgecols <- intersect(c("fill", "colour", "linetype", "shape", "size", "alpha"), colnames(data))
    if (length(dodgecols) == 0) {
      abort("`position_jitterdodge()` requires at least one aesthetic to dodge by")
    }
    ndodge    <- lapply(data[dodgecols], levels)  # returns NULL for numeric, i.e. non-dodge layers
    ndodge    <- length(unique(unlist(ndodge)))
    
    list(
      dodge.width = self$dodge.width,
      spread.sep = self$spread.sep %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * .05),
      spread.width = spread.width / (ndodge + 2),
      flipped_aes = flipped_aes
    )
  },
  
  compute_panel = function(data, params, scales) {
    data <- flip_data(data, params$flipped_aes)
    data <- ggplot2:::collide(data, params$dodge.width, "position_jitterdodge", ggplot2:::pos_dodge,
      check.width = FALSE)
    
    f <- function(sep, i, n) {
      m <- ceiling(max(n) / 2)
      
      ifelse(
        as.logical(n %% 2), 
        sep * c(0, rep(1:m, each = 2) * rep(c(-1, 1), m))[i],
        sep * (rep(1:m, each = 2)[i] - 1 / 2) * rep(c(-1, 1), m)
      )
    }
    
    trans_x <- if(params$spread.width > 0) function(df) {
      df |>
        group_by(x, y) |>
        mutate(
          i = 1:n(),
          n = n(),
          sep = pmin(params$spread.sep, 2 * params$spread.width / n),
          adj = f(sep, i, n)
        ) |>
        magrittr::extract2("adj")
    }
    
    x_aes <- intersect(ggplot2:::ggplot_global$x_aes, names(data))
    y_aes <- intersect(ggplot2:::ggplot_global$y_aes, names(data))
    x <- if (length(x_aes) == 0) 0 else data[[x_aes[1]]]
    y <- if (length(y_aes) == 0) 0 else data[[y_aes[1]]]
    dummy_data <- vctrs::new_data_frame(list(x = x, y = y), nrow(data))
    x_adj <- trans_x(dummy_data) |> unclass()

    
    # Apply Spread
    data <- transform_position(data, function(x) x + x_adj)
    flip_data(data, params$flipped_aes)
  }
)
```

When trying to run `document()` with either of these functions in the package, I get the error "Error: `_inherit` must be a ggproto object."  I cannot figure out what the error is trying to tell me, which makes it impossible to fix.  It's clearly an issue with the documentation I've added, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Seeing as you use `ggplot::function()` throughout, have you tried using `ggproto("PositionSpreaddodge", ggplot2::Position, ...)`? My guess is that you haven't imported the Position ggproto in your namespace. Alternatively you can use `#' @importFrom ggplot2 Position` as a roxygen comment.

Comment: Thank you.  You basically have the answer, but I missed more than just ggplot2::Position - I had function() multiple times where I needed ggplot2::function().  I'll add the corrections as an answer when it lets me so that anyone who wants this has a version that "just works", in or out of a package.